# Error creating zip file by refid

Tags: ant, fileset

I'm trying to create 2 zip files as part of an ant task. Both are similar, but one includes some extra data. So to reduce code I'd like to define a fileset and reference it. The only problem is that produces an error.

Task:

```
<target name="create-zips" depends="cleanup, compile, package-jar">

    <zipfileset id="zipfiles">
        <zipfileset dir="${ant.project.name}-dist" includes="${jarname}.jar" prefix="${title}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${scripts.dir}" includes="myprogram" filemode="755" prefix="${title}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${scripts.dir}" includes="myprogram_gui" filemode="755" prefix="${title}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${scripts.dir}" includes="myprogram_gui.command" filemode="755" prefix="${title}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${scripts.dir}" includes="myprogram.bat" filemode="755" prefix="${title}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${scripts.dir}" includes="myprogram_gui.bat" filemode="755" prefix="${title}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${docs.dir}" includes="myprogram_readme.txt" prefix="${title}"/>
    </zipfileset>

    <zip destfile="${deploy.dir}/myprogram_${version}.zip" whenempty="fail" defaultexcludes="true">
         <zipfileset refid="zipfiles"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${otherdata.dir}" includes="other/*.*" prefix="${title}"/>
    </zip>
    <zip destfile="${deploy.dir}/myprogram_noother_${version}.zip" whenempty="fail" defaultexcludes="true">
        <zipfileset refid="zipfiles"/>
    </zip>
</target>
```

When task is run:

```
    create-zips:

BUILD FAILED
/path/to/my/buildfile/build-tools.xml:119: Problem opening /path/to/my/data/docs/myprogram_readme.txt
```

I've verified that the file exists. Removing the readme include just makes the error happen on a different file. Also, if I just copy and paste the zipfileset into 2 separate  tags everything works fine. But I'd rather not do that.

edit: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on October 14 2011, Mac OS X 10.7. Haven't tried on any other platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying once to do the same, to no avail. A `fileset` does not accept nested `fileset`. When you try to cheat and use `zipfileset` as the outer set, ant considers its content as zip files. When ant tries to unzip your files, you get *opening error*.

A `fileset` must have `dir` attribute. This dir must be parent to all fileset components. Sad but true.

I ended up in workaround. Create X filesets. Those filesets may be specified as nested elements of a `zip` task. If in a given case you need less than X, then make a default for all X filesets, and zip always all X.

```
<!-- define X empty filesets -->
<fileset dir="c:\temp\1" includes="asdfasdf.neverhappens" id="nullfileset" />
<fileset id="zipfileset2" refid="nullfileset" />
<fileset id="zipfileset3" refid="nullfileset" />

<!-- here go real sets -->
<zipfileset dir="${scripts.dir}" includes="myprogram" />
```

Be careful about ant filesets. They are mutable. I wrote once a "question" about it, but someone deleted it. Well done quiet job, stack folks, "thanks" for that.

EDIT1: On Linux one could try `dir="/"` and use [`selector`s](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) nested inside a `fileset`. I was on Windows with my problem, so I couldn't do that. There's no "/" on Windows and I was gathering files from different drives.

Comment: That makes a certain amount of sense, although it would be nice to nest filesets. I could probably use selectors in my case, since there is a parent directory for all the relevant files.

Comment: But I recalled another problem with that. I wasn't able to cut the paths and zip held the whole path from the root to my files. Maybe you will be able to fix it somehow.